# Play 2 Framework controller query parameter validation

Tags: validation, playframework, playframework-2.2

Dear Playframework users.

I have switched to play framework 2.2 and I have a question on validation. I hope someone can point me to the right direction.

I have a controller to fetch a collection.

```
GET        /country  controllers.api.CountryController.list(fetchInactive: Int ?= 0, sortBy: String ?= "name", sortDir: String ?= "asc" )

public static Result list( int fetchInactive, String sortBy, String sortDir)
```

it works great, although I would like to LIMIT the possible values one can send as sortBy field directive.

E.g. a list of elements. like 'name','id' etc.
In play 1 it is very easy to validate controller parameters. see [Play Framework: automatic validation of controller methods applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559410/play-framework-automatic-validation-of-controller-methods-applied)

I know how to use JSR-303 with Models, although here this is an API and I want to validate the individual parameters.

Could someone give me a hint or a example how I can achieve that?

I would like to use annotations to define my own validator to validate that sortBy only accepts certain strings values.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Actually in this case you should use default values for `sortBy` and `sortDir` if user gives something out of allowed range, you can do it easily within the action (don't need to use validator)

```
public static Result list(Integer fetchInactive, String sortBy, String sortDir) {
    Integer resolvedFetchInactive
            = (fetchInactive != null && Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2).contains(fetchInactive)) ? fetchInactive : 0;

    String resolvedSortBy
            = (sortBy != null && Arrays.asList("name", "id").contains(sortBy)) ? sortBy : "name";

    String resolvedSortDir
            = (sortDir != null && Arrays.asList("asc", "desc").contains(sortDir)) ? sortDir : "asc";

    if (!resolvedSortBy.equals(sortBy) || !resolvedSortDir.equals(sortDir) || !resolvedFetchInactive.equals(fetchInactive)) {
        //redirect to the same list with allowed values
        return redirect(routes.Application.list(resolvedFetchInactive, resolvedSortBy, resolvedSortDir));
    }

    return ok("You're going to display list sorted by: " + resolvedSortBy + " " + resolvedSortDir + ", fetchInactive is: " + resolvedFetchInactive);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response this is ok. I wanted to avoid having to duplicate code as I have this in some of my controllers. I was hoping to implement a validation using annotations, and in the annotation parameter I could specify the values I can accept. This work so nicelly in Play 1.x. Can I use Spring validation and AOP then ? or Should I implement a validator using annotations using Action composition ? Any idea ?